# Want to Show exit popup if the visitor wants to leave before spends 10 Seconds at lest

Tags: javascript, popup, popupwindow

I want to show a popup to my user to my blog posts only if a user spends less than 20 seconds in a post and wants to leave. When he or she wants to leave then I want to show the exit popup. I have create a popup for this and now it shows when anyone goes to close the window. I set a function window.onload. I have my code below here. But its not working still

```
var runspopup = true;

function popfunc(){
     runspopup = false;
}

window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(popfunc, 20000);
}


  const show = () => {
  const element = document.querySelector(".mbt-exit-popup");
  element.style.visibility = "visible";
  element.style.opacity = "1";
  element.style.transform = "scale(1)";
  element.style.transition = "0.4s, opacity 0.4s";
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.addEventListener("mouseout", (event) => {
    if (!event.toElement && !event.relatedTarget && runspopup == true) {
        show();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `window.onbeforeunload`

Comment: @David how to set the time there with this function.. ? Can you please provide me a complete answer using above code please

Comment: Use a global boolean variable which you set to false after 10 seconds. On window.onbeforeunload, check that variable, and if true, show your popup. If false, do nothing.